# invalid opcode: REVERT

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I am new to ethereum and smart contracts, and I am trying to deploy a smart contract to my local blockchain that I created using geth and connected to remix via the **External HTTP Provider**.

I am deploying the **1_Storage.sol** file, which is present by default in the directory.

The file compiles successfully, but when I try to deploy it, this error appears

[image]

When I click on send Transaction, it didn't work.

Here is the my pragma statement

[image]

And the gas values

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to deploy the contract with the `100 wei` amount. The `1_Storage.sol` contract doesn't have a payable constructor, so it doesn't need any amount of ETH as input.

Just set the `Value` back to 0 and the code will deploy perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, Now the remix console is stuck in "creation of Storage pending..." and no contract is shown to interact with

Comment: Which network are you deploying it to?

Comment: I am deploying to my local http geth provider, but I found the solution, it looks like I must be minig blocks in order for the contract to be deployed, I thought geth will automatically start mining blocks when a contract is getting deployed, but it didn't. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad it worked :)